# How to respond when someone says 'It means a lot'?

Tags: phrase-choice

In a scenario where you have encouraged someone but haven't helped them physically or with your time and they say "It means a lot". Just for the words you said. Can you respond with

- Any time?
- No problem?
- You are welcome?

I am not a native speaker. I've seen these phrases used after you have done someone a favor.

Context: Someone showed good performance in sports after struggling to perform in multiple matches. You said:

> Person 1: Congratulations for your great performance. I am happy for you!
>   Person 2: It means a lot!
>   Person 1: ???

Comment: "It means a lot (to me)" is essentially the same as "thank you", so respond as you would to that.

Comment: **That means a lot to me**.

Answer (score 3):

All are generally acceptable for a response. I find that my response changes based on how well I know the person or not.

If I am fairly familiar with them (close friend or good friend) I may say:

> Hey no worries!

or
 used in rare occasions that you want to acknowledge and show you are happy that your words meant a lot to them:

> I'm glad!

If someone says it that I am not so familiar I tend to respond:

> You're welcome!

English is weird where there are many ways to say the same thing. Many responses are appropriate for the same thing. I would just say what you feel is a natural response.

I prefer "no worries", others may say "no problem". Pretty much the same meaning or implied meaning using a different word.

In the above example you provided, their response of "that means a lot" can be interpreted as saying:

> Hey, I am glad you acknowledged my hard work and dedication to improving so it means a lot, thanks!

So I would word your response as if you are responding to that :) In the end as I said, there are many ways to respond and all the above are equally appropriate. Find one that feels natural to you and go with it!

Comment: As you say, in the situation where the athlete played a good game, a custom response like “Keep up the good work!” might be fitting.

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker, I most commonly say "of course!" Which is similar to no problem. I find it flows the best and sounds the nicest, but it has to be said with a cheery vocal tone or else it could sound assholeish

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, 99 out of 100 times a pursing of the lips and a nod of the head are the most utilized response, ending the exchange before it as that will eliminate any further awkwardness.